# Eigenvalues of a Continuous spectrum

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces, eigenfunctions

I'm stuck with this question:
Given a self-adjoint linear operator A, consider the values ​​of u belonging to R(Real space) for which the resolver exists, is densely defined but is not limited. Discuss what the u values represent  ​​in this case.
if they exist,there are eigenfunctions of A associated to u?
In what sense these latter can be seen as the limit of Hilbert space elements that are approximate eingenvector of A .
Consider, for example, the case of the momentum operator.